# FactoryGirl conditional attribute

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, factory-bot

I have a factory attribute called type. Right now it works for one string. How can I make it so I use the same factory but use it with another string `type 'Quiz'`. So, I want to test if the `type 'PhotoUploadCampaign'` then run the PhotoUpload attributes for that factory. If the `type 'Quiz'` then run Quiz attributes for that factory.

Factory campaign file

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :campaign do    
    type 'PhotoUploadCampaign'
  end
end
```

Campaign step file

```
Given(/^there's a photo upload campaign$/) do
  @campaign = create(:campaign)
end
```

Comment: What does "run the PhotoUpload attributes" mean? Do you want to set some default values for these (PhotoUpload) attributes or do you want to pass themc as arguments of the factory call `create(:compaign)?`

Comment: For example `@campaign.type returns "PhotoUploadCampaign"` How would I use it in my step definition to select  `@campaign.type returns "Quiz"` without having to manually change my FactoryGirl file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With factory girl you can specify attributes when you create or build the factory.

The definition you have now is just the default.

In your specs you can do

```
@campaign = create(:campaign, type: 'Quiz')
```

This will do the same logic as before, but with `Quiz` instead of `PhotoUploadCampaign`